# Is this object casting good practice? Also, is there a better way?

Tags: c#, casting

I'm currently receiving a serialized object through a socket connection, this works flawlessly. I'm deserializing it fine also. Now, I want the client to send more than one object type (or class) through the network.

This is how i deserialize my object onto it's Type 'MyClass':

```
var m = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(dataReceived));
var b = new BinaryFormatter();
var o = (MyClass)b.Deserialize(m);
```

Now, if I'd like to receive more than 1 object type I could either make a method that can cast it to any type supported or send a header which will tell me the type the object is and then cast it. I prefer the *FIRST* way.

The thing is, I can't cast it with GetType() of course, and using the name property would result in something with a switch of strings which I dislike. So I decided I could do either:

```
object objectReceived = b.Deserialize(m);

if(o is MyClass){

    MyClass myClass = (MyClass) objectReceived;

}
else if (o is AnotherClass){

    AnotherClass myOtherClass = (AnotherClass) objectReceived;

}
```

(I could also do something with the as operator, but that will make me check for nulls afterwards. For example)

```
var MyClass = objectReceived as MyClass; 
var AnotherClass = objectReceived as AnotherClass
```

*OR* I could implement an interface that every object sent through the network will implement, cast the object as that interface, which will return it's type, and then cast it accordingly!

The thing is, I already have that working code, but I can't figure out a clean way to code that interface. What should the interface's method return? A type? A string? I don't know really. This is why I tell myself: well, as I have working code, if it's good practice and easy to maintain, I won't get myself into the trouble of making an interface which I don't know how to now because of time constraints.

So that's my question: Is my approach correct/good practice? Or is the interface approach better?

Thanks a lot for your help guys!!

Comment: With regards to the return value, optimally you would want to return a type that is as compact as possible for the required number of classes and supports fast comparison (ie switching).  (An int maybe?)

Comment: out of interest do these different objects have stuff in common (ie all derived from a given type, etc.) or are they totally independant objects?

Comment: No but they could, what I wanted is them to have the INTERFACE in common =). Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not use Generics?

You can create a common deserialization method like so:

```
private T MyDeserialize<T>(String dataReceived)
{
    var m = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(dataReceived)); 
    var b = new BinaryFormatter(); 
    return (T)b.Deserialize(m); 
}
```

Any then call it like:

```
MyClass myClassInstance = MyDeserialize<MyClass>(dataReceived);
```

---

**Generics**

With generics when you call  `MyDeserialize<MyClass>(dataReceived);` you make the method think that `T` is `MyClass`.

Imagine it doing this:

```
private MyClass MyDeserialize(String dataReceived)
{
    var m = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(dataReceived)); 
    var b = new BinaryFormatter(); 
    return (MyClass)b.Deserialize(m); 
}
```

Obviously you can pass any Type (class if you prefer) you like in between the `<>`'s and it will use that type instead.

Comment: Because I've no idea what that means. Literally: you lost me with the <T> thingy =(. Thanks a lot though, I will research on that. Do you have any starting point so I can learn how to code a method with <T> like that? I know how to use the <> operators as in List<int> but I've no idea how to CODE them.

Comment: `T` is a generic Type (it can be any Type you want). So when you call the method with `<MyClass>` you can imagine `T` been `MyClass`. Have a look here for an introduction: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6207/Generics-C

Comment: OOOOOOOH I see, T is a generic type all types derivate from? Now I get everything! You can pass the actual type between the greater and smaller signs!! Then the (T) cast would become a typecast according the type you passed through the <> thingys!! WOW! Thanks a lot man!!!!

Comment: You can also constraint `T` to be of a particular type or interface. e.g. `where T : IMyInterface` now what ever you pass as `T` must implement IMyInterface *at compile time*

Answer (score 2):

I think, potentially, the source of your problem is that you are trying to do too many things in one method.  Either your method is doing the same thing with all the different types of objects (in which case they should all share the same interface and you should cast them all to that), or, as I suspect, you are doing different things with each of them, in which case it's not good practice to combine all that logic into one method, or even one class, for that matter.

So, if you had methods like this:

```
private void processObject(MyClass obj) { //... }
private void processObject(AnotherClass obj) { //... }
```

Then, in your method that deserializes the objects, you could simply check the class name from the message header, and then call the right method:

```
switch(className)
{
    case ClassNameEnum.MyClass: processObject((MyClass)b.Deserialize(m)); break;
    case ClassNameEnum.AnotherClass: processObject((AnotherClass)b.Deserialize(m)); break;
}
```

As I show in this example, using an enumeration is better than using strings to specify the type in the message header.  It's smaller data, a faster comparison, and doesn't allow for misspellings.  If you do want to use strings so that the messages are more readable, that's fine, but you should use constants for the strings.

Using a generic method to deserialize the objects is an excellent suggestion, in which case the switch code would look like this:

```
switch(className)
{
    case ClassNameEnum.MyClass: processObject(Deserialize<MyClass>(m)); break;
    case ClassNameEnum.AnotherClass: processObject(Deserialize<AnotherClass>(m)); break;
}
```

However, doing so doesn't really alleviate anything.  You still have to add a separate `case` statement for each type.  If you want to keep strong-typing, there is no magic bullet to get rid of this extra coding.  The whole point of casting is to inform the compiler which type you are using *at compile time*.  If there was some way to cast it to a type that is determined at run-time, it would be utterly pointless.  If you don't care about the advantages of strong-typing, you could make it a `dynamic` variable, in which case you could use any type without casting it at all (this requires .NET 4).

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I was thinking when I made my comment (before seeing this answer). In fact so identical that I'll go ditch my comment. :) +1 for pointing out that you need to work out if the objects are the same or totally differet, +1 for switching on the header string (though I do not that Damieh said he didn't like switcing on strings but is happy with this). Sadly my +1 buttons seems to be not workign any more so I can't give these +1s to this answer. ;-)

Comment: I just read your updated answer. The enum thingy made it even better. I will certainly do this approach!! If I could accept both answers I would, but unfortunately it only lets me accept one. I can only upvote this one. Thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 1):

There is no much difference which casting you will use. The only difference between:

```
x = (Type) deserialized;
```

and

```
x = deserialized as Type;
```

is that the first one will raise an InvalidCastException if deserialized is not of Type, while the second will return null in `x`.
As @DaveShaw explained - using generics is a very good approach, but it depends on your architecture if there are no better ways to do what you want.

Comment: Yes, I knew that difference between the casts. Also, if you wanna go further: the as keyword is equivalent to x = deserialized is type ? (type)deserialized : (type)null. Great answer though, I will use generics as daveshaw said! =)